# Strong Parameters : Hash param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a form where I have a table with checkboxes in order to select rows and save IDs in my DB.

But it throws me an error:

> Param is missing or the value is empty: leadallocation"

I tried different ways but still nor working. So at the moment I just wand to save the hash in my db. Thanks.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def leadallocation_params
  params.require(:leadallocation).permit(:campaign_id, :company_id, :user_id)
end
```

Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GruGL758jT4FO+t/BTRGLrD2uCGOj/qUCrB5VswquzR9N7JZ/rouLmGZnTE7A+XTARiLwkOy1n3/zMqhzuenmg==",
 "company_ids"=>["38",
 "40"],
 "commit"=>"Create Leadallocation"}
```

The controller

```
class LeadallocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_leadallocation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /leadallocations
  # GET /leadallocations.json
  def complete
  end


  def index
    @leadallocations = Leadallocation.all
  end

  # GET /leadallocations/1
  # GET /leadallocations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /leadallocations/new
  def new


    @leadallocation = Leadallocation.new
    @comps =  Company.all
  end

  # GET /leadallocations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /leadallocations
  # POST /leadallocations.json
  def create

    @leadallocation = Leadallocation.new(leadallocation_params)

    @leadallocation.company_id = params[:company_ids]


    respond_to do |format|
      if @leadallocation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @leadallocation, notice: 'Leadallocation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @leadallocation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @leadallocation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /leadallocations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /leadallocations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @leadallocation.update(leadallocation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @leadallocation, notice: 'Leadallocation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @leadallocation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @leadallocation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /leadallocations/1
  # DELETE /leadallocations/1.json
  def destroy
    @leadallocation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to leadallocations_url, notice: 'Leadallocation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_leadallocation
      @leadallocation = Leadallocation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def leadallocation_params
      params.require(:leadallocation).permit(:campaign_id, :company_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

The models

```
class Leadallocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :activities
  belongs_to :campaign
  has_many :leadallocations

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  has_many :subsidiaries
  has_many :leadallocations
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :leads
  has_many :activities
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :users
has_many :leadallocations

end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :leadallocations
```

The view

```
    <h1>New Leadallocation</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Companies</h1>
<%= simple_form_for(@leadallocation) do |f| %>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th> 
      <th>Country</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comps.each do |company| %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "company_ids[]", company.id %></td>
        <td><%= company.name %></td>
        <td><%= company.country %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', leadallocations_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using Strong Params requires that your parameters adhere to a specific form.

In this case, you params need to be nested under the key `leadallocation`

The problem is in your form, instead of `check_box_tag`, you will want to do `f.check_box` and use [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) to see the available options.

This will nest your attributes under the `leadallocation`, if it doesn't then something might be wrong with your setup of models and forms.

Basically all this is to say you want to change your params from this:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"GruGL758jT4FO+t/BTRGLrD2uCGOj/qUCrB5VswquzR9N7JZ/rouLmGZnTE7A+XTARiLwkOy1n3/zMqhzuenmg==",
  "company_ids"=>["38",
  "40"],
  "commit"=>"Create Leadallocation"}
```

to this:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"GruGL758jT4FO+t/BTRGLrD2uCGOj/qUCrB5VswquzR9N7JZ/rouLmGZnTE7A+XTARiLwkOy1n3/zMqhzuenmg==",
  "leadallocation" => {
    "company_ids"=>["38","40"]
  }
  "commit"=>"Create Leadallocation"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
"company_ids"=>["38", "40"]
```

It *should* be:

```
"leadallocation" => {
    "company_ids" => ["38", "40"]
}
```

This is the standard construct for a Rails object to be passed to your db. This is why [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) is structured the way it is...

```
params.require(:top_level_param).permit(:child_params)
```

--

You *can* get around this by simply using `.permit`:

```
#app/controllers/leadallocations_controller.rb
class LeadAllocationsController < ApplicationController
    private
    def leadallocation_params
       params.permit(:company_ids)
     end
end
```

This is not a permanent fix but a HACK!!!

## Fix:

```
#app/views/lead_allocations/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @leadallocations do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :company_ids, Company.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

References here:

> - [Simple Form `collection_check_boxes`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_check_boxes)
> - [Rails `collection_check_boxes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

This *should* send the data you require back to your controller. Notice the `f.___` -- this tells Rails to build a form using the [`FormBuilder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) you've invoked around `@leadallocations`.

Simply, this means that your data will be encapsulated in the `{"leadallocations" => ...}` params, whereas if you just use `check_box_tag`, it will assume the data is independent.

Also, *never* use HTML to stylize your page. The use of `<br>` and `<table>` should *only* be for formatting. CSS is the only way to stylize your application. [Your use of `<table>` *seems* to be okay](http://collaboradev.com/2014/07/07/never-use-html-tables-ever/); I just wanted to highlight because most people don't get the idea of HTML vs CSS.

---

Furthermore, there is another problem - with your associations:

```
class Leadallocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

You cannot assign multiple company ID's to a [`belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) relationship:

[image]

I've seen instances where `[foreign_key]_ids` can be passed, but it's not recommended; indeed, an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

What you'll be looking for is [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

[image]

```
#app/models/leadallocation.rb
class LeadAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :company
end

#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :leadallocations
end

#join table - companies_leadallocations
```

This will definitely permit you associate multiple `leadallocations` per company and vice versa.